# Why is that Gildarts not too involved in guild fights?

Tags: fairy-tail

There are so many situations where the Fairy-tail guild gets into really tough fights and in serious trouble!. Gildarts is extremely strong, how is that he is not very involved in fights??

Comment: Because Gildarts is like the older generation of Fairy Tail. Having him shouting around like Natsu and bashing people with nakama-power would be...kinda weird (personally I think it'd be hilarious though), considering that the main demography for Fairy Tail is young boys. In short, having Gildarts very involved in guild fights would be less appealing than having Natsu blowing fire on the enemies or Gray striping naked.

Comment: he can't control his power really well. . . if he fight with his guildmates around him then friendly fire will happen

Answer (score 1):

As said before Gildarts is a class S mage and he is almost always adventuring. For example there was an episode when Gildarts came to the Guild and everyone was doing a party.(I don´t remember in which episode it happened thought). Even if he wanted to join the fight´s he would need some "days" to reach the "battlefield".

Comment: hmm ya...probably

Answer (score 1):

Well he can't hold back when it comes to his powers and if he did fight like that someone would be dead or severely injured. But there is also that he is almost never at the guild.

Answer (score 1):

well since he being an S class Wizard is busy in far off lands dealing greater ,maybe he doesn't even know about them or the battles may be finished by the time he reaches and it isn't much interesting if the big guys get involved to...

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Guildarts isn't always around. You may recall there is a special board with S rank jobs for S rank wizards, and those missions are intense. So while the guild may be having trouble with one thing, Guildarts is likely far away handling a different job of immense difficulty as well. He simply may be busy and unable to leave.

Answer (score -1):

http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Gildarts_Clive
The above link is a bibliography about Gildarts Clive and it also mentions why he doesn't fight often, not in a more clear way though. One of the reasons why I think he doesn't fight like he used to be, after the casualties he faced in the battle with Achonologia which nearly killed him. Yeah, but if you want more info just take a look at the link above.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Whilst the link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Because Gildarts uses the magic "crash". If he participated in fights, the anime would be boring because he would just touch the enemy, and make them CRASH.

Basically, he's too powerful.

Answer (score -2):

1.He isn't around most of the time, doing so called decade or century quests as he is a S-Class wizard.
2.Natsu and the guild need to show how strong their plot armor and friendship power can be, instead of raw firepower.
3.It's no fun to watch OP characters enter mid fight and defeat villains with ease.